# Can I get via javascript the HTTP expires header of a HTTP resource?

Tags: javascript, http-headers

My page needs to know when the cache a included javascript file will expire, to retrieve it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [XMLHTTPRequest object](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) has a [`getResponseHeader` method](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-getresponseheader-method) you can call:

```
// The following script:
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open("GET", "test.txt", true);
client.send();
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 2) {
        alert(client.getResponseHeader("Expires"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Note you can use `HEAD` rather than `GET` if you just want the header info to avoid downloading the whole file, and it is probably best to call `client.send();`
 *after* you have assigned the `onreadystatechange` event handler.